# Oracle replaces £ with ?? on INSERT

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I have an Oracle 12c database that is replacing `£` with `??` on `INSERT`. The insert is coming from a 11.2 instant client SQL*Plus session. Both boxes are running Linux.

The same also happens from SQL*Plus on the DB host itself.

The DB host has the following settings:

- `$LANG`: en_GB.UTF8
- `NLS_CHARACTERSET`: AL32UTF8

The Client has:

- `$LANG`: en_GB.UTF-8

`$NLS_LANG` is not set for either DB or Client hosts.

```
select dump('£', 1017) from dual;

DUMP('??',1017)
-----------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: ef,bf,bd,ef,bf,bd
```

**EDIT:** Correction. Only `£` is being replaced, but is being replaced with `??`

Comment: Is it actually replaced in the table, or just appears so when you query it? Check out the `dump()` function to see what is actually stored. What is the `NLS_LANG` for the sessions that insert and query?

Comment: Also check the source is actually the character you think, [not something similar](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm). Particularly the (apparently) dollar sign; not being able to see that would be strange if it's a normal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing [the Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm). It looks like your Linux environment setting for [the Oracle `NLS_LANG` variable](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#GUID-86A29834-AE29-4BA5-8A78-E19C168B690A) is not appropriate:

```
$ export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.US7ASCII"
$ sqlplus ...

SQL> select dump('£', 1017) from dual;

DUMP('??',1017)
-----------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: ef,bf,bd,ef,bf,bd
```

With a setting that matches your `LANG` it works as expected:

```
$ export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.AL32UTF8"
$ sqlplus ...

SQL> select dump('£', 1017) from dual;

DUMP('£',1017)
-----------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c2,a3
```

which is [the Unicode pound sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a3/index.htm).